# latexmk file not found in a alpine linux docker container

Tags: latexmk, includegraphics

I can for whatever reason not use `latexmk` in a docker container.

The problem itself comes up in my alpine docker container with `texlive-full` container and in an temporary created `ubuntu:latest` docker container, although I can create the document in my arch linux and manjaro installation.

The following is a minimal respresentation of the `LaTeX` code which yields a documents on both, the arch linux and manjaro installation, but yields the same error (  `'! LaTeX Error: File 'logo' not found.'`) on both containers:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}
\end{document}
```

Here is the full log from my container (anwait/latex) which only has the `texlive-full` and `biber` packages installed:

```sh
host$ docker run -itv $PWD:/workdir anwait/latex sh

/workdir # latexmk
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible
    with file requests.
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
Rule 'latex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'latex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex  -recorder  "minimal.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Alpine Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def) (./minimal.aux)

! LaTeX Error: File `logo' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}
                                                 
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on minimal.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'logo' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `logo' not found.'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was made
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

### Sidenote

Yes I can avoid this error by writing `logo.png` instead of `logo` (the file itself is a png file) but...

1. then I'm getting this error: `! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in logo.png (no BoundingBox).`
2. I do not want to use this form at all because I want to be free of this restriction in the source file and because it works on arch linux and manjaro without it... so I am more interested in what I am missing.

Comment: You're running standard latex it does not support png files! Run pdflatex, with latexmk that is `latexmk -pdf`

Comment: Also never use the minimal class for anything, use article for things like this. The minimal class is (AFAIK) for some internal testing, but doesn't setup a lot of tjings so packages my get confused

Comment: thanks @daleif, I have not checked the global config and forgot the fact that I have a `.latexmkrc` in my home dir on both installations but not in the container which was the reason for this weird error, will update the container asap

Comment: Also be aware that on Alpine a full TeX Live does not necessarily contain everything it would contain e.g. on Ubuntu. Tools like xindy or biber might not work there. The images of the Island of TeX (https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive) might serve as a base for further experiments with full TeX Live in containers.

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician, I will check this one out when I stumble on another problem with this container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was truly the missing `-pdf` flag as @daleif mentioned, which I forgot to include in the command, when working with the shell inside the container because I have a `$HOME/.latexmkrc`with this exact option enabled on my workstation and because I haven't used this image for too long.